# frames behind pictures?

Tags: html, graphics, iframe, embed

My question is related to HTML, and PURE html. I am working on a new design for my front page on a social network called kwick, and I want to create a kind of space for my favorite Video at the moment.

Now my problem is, how do I realize something like this:

I take a picture of my ipod like that(just an example, its not my ipod)
<s>http://www.clein-online.de/schmuck_projekte/files/ipod_nano_schutzhuelle.jpg</s>

Now I want to create this picture as gif and cut out the display, now behind that cutten out area, there should be a youtube video be shown, in a way that the embed player is NOT shown completely, i mean, the player is there completely, but the picture is a lay in on it.

How to do this?

Comment: What parts of the player do you want to hide? There may be an option to turn these parts off in the embed code editor on youtube's site.

Comment: maybe the contol and timeline, i only need the play button, which is in the beginning of the video in the middle of the screen. and, i want to have the complete ipod-screen be filled with the video, so i mean, i would prefer cutting 20 pixels away dann having a 20 pixel border around the vid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cut the image at all. Make a div that has enough space for the whole picture of the ipod and use CSS to make it the background image (can be inline styles if you can't add your own CSS files).

```
<div style="background:url(ipod.jpg); width:300px; height:400px;">
    <iframe src="..." style="margin: 25px auto 0;" width: 250px; height: 200px;></iframe>
</div>
```

Apply margin, width and height to your `iframe` or `embed` or `object` to position it within the div that has the ipod background image.

You can set the iframe to the size you need and make it hide any overflow if necessary but I don't think you're going to be able to hide parts of the flash if you don't have control of the embed code.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest hurdle will be ensuring that your **WMODE = transparent**. Setting WMODE to transparent will keep your flash crap from always appearing on top of other content. Then, simply position an image with transparency in the correct place over the video.

Since you haven't included any information on how precisely you're including your flash file, I can't really tell you what method you'll need to use to set the WMODE. Just do some googling, and all will be clear.